# How to hide view when click on tableview Delegate in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tableview

I am working on Xamarin iOS platform and I have open one view having `TableView`. I want to hide popup view when `RowSelected` delegate method call

Here is my code:

In `TableDatasource.cs` :

```
using UIKit;


namespace NewProject.IOS
{
    public class MapFilterDataSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        MainViewController controller;
        protected string[] tableItems;
        protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";
        MapViewController owner;
        public static string StrSelectedRow = "Intial";
        int index = -1;

        string[] arrCrimePerson = new string[] { "asd", "asd", "Acte asd", "asd", "a", "asd" };
        string[] arrCrimeProperie = new string[]{ "asd", "asd", "Acte asd", "asd", "a", "asd" };
        string[] arrStupefiants = new string[] { "asd", "asd", "Acte asd", "asd", "a", "asd" };

        public MapFilterDataSource(string[] items, MapViewController owner)
        {
            tableItems = items;
            this.owner = owner;

        }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
MapViewController.StrSelectedValue = "Autre";
                    MapViewController obj = new MapViewController();
                    obj.HidePopUp();
}
```

In `MainViewController.cs`:

```
public override async void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    CreateTableItems();
}

public virtual void HidePopUp()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Button " + StrSelectedValue + " clicked");

    viewPopUp.RemoveFromSuperview();
    // This viewPopUp i want to hide but its crashing here showing error like "system.argumentnullexception value cannot be null"
}

protected void CreateTableItems()
{           
    List<string> tableItems = new List<string>();
    tableItems.Add("asd");
    tableItems.Add("sdf");
    tableItems.Add("sdf");
    tableItems.Add("aaa");

    tblFilter.TableFooterView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0));
    tblFilter.Source = new MapFilterDataSource(tableItems.ToArray(), this);
}
```

Comment: did you add the viewPopUp to your View? Post full code

Comment: yes i have added that view pop in MapviewController.designer.cs file

Comment: [Outlet]
     UIKit.UIView ViewPopUp { get; set; }

Comment: view pop is not nil initially i show/hide this view on button click.but when i am trying it with delegate its crashing

Comment: post full code of your datasource and viewcontroller

Comment: but where please give any link where i can post my code

Comment: edit your question and post code

Comment: I have edited please check

Comment: Hi HeisenBerg did you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to hide a view in your ViewController from the DataSource, pass your ViewController's instance to the DataSource (via construtor)

```
public class MyDataSource : UITableViewSource
{
    MainViewController controller;
    List<string> tableItems

    public ProgramArticlesTableSource (List<string> tableItems, MainViewController controller)
    {
        this.tableItems = tableItems;
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    ......
```

then call HidePopup method in RowSelected.

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    controller.HidePopUp();
}
```

Comment: public MapFilterDataSource(string[] items, MapViewController owner)
  {
   tableItems = items;
   this.owner = owner;

  }

Comment: its not crashing now

Comment: but its not hiding that pop up

Comment: wait Bro its Done

Comment: call owner.HidePopUp() inside RowSelected.

Comment: You Are such a saviour Anna hats off